# how to monitor mobile data usage but exclude wi-fi

Tags: data-monitoring

I'm aware there are a large number of data monitoring apps for android but as far as I can see, they all include wi-fi usage in the total.

Since my wi-fi usage is unmetered, I only want to monitor 3g mobile data usage. is there an app that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [My Data Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=en).  It monitors network and Wi-Fi data.  If you have at least Android 4.0 [it should also allow you](http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-monitor-data-usage-on-android) to view the data use directly without having to install any additional apps.

Comment: Hmm, after further inspection, it seems that onavo doesn't include wi-fi data, even though it claims to. Maybe I have got completely the wrong end of the stick, and in fact none of these apps monitor wi-fi data (though I'm not sure why they would claim to because 99% of people wouldn't want that). I'm confused but at least I have a solution :-)

Comment: @Andy check out my solution if that helps your problem..the mobile and wifi network usage is displayed by date separtely..

Answer (score 0):

In your Android: Check under *Settings › Data usage › Mobile,* as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Where do you see the option for "Mobile"?  A screenshot might be useful.

Comment: Like this one, @MatthewRead? :) AFAIK you need to enable that explicitly via the (3-dot-) overflow-menu. By default, WiFi is excluded – so OP would already get what asked for.

Comment: @Izzy Interesting, I do not see these tabs on my devices nor does the overflow menu offer an option!

Comment: @MatthewRead I didn't check that lately. I remember I've played with that on 4.0. Just checked: It's still there on 4.1 (no overflow-menu, but hitting the menu button reveals the option: stock ROM on my LG O4X), and also on 4.3 (same as described for 4.1; CM on my Moto Milestone²). Cannot say for 4.4 and up, as I have no device running that. So I'd say: try the menu button – if there is one :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check out [Internet Speed meter Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.internet.speed.meter.lite&hl=en). You can measure the downloaded data either on a mobile and wifi network and get stats for each day and for each month measured by the app separately(Check screenshot). And its available as a free and ad-free Lite version. For advanced features use the [Pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.internet.speed.meter).

Features mentioned on Playstore,

> Lite Features:
>
> - Real time speed update in status bar and notification.
> - Daily traffic usage in notification.
> - Separate stats for Mobile network and WiFi network.
> - Monitors your traffic data for the last 30 days.
> - Battery efficient

[image: Screenshot]

<sub>Screenshot (Click for larger image)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool app to monitor 3g mobile data usage as well as wifi.

Download this app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdogpro&hl=en

It also has a Lite version for free, check out that. I am sure you will like this app more because it generates graphs too for each hour, day, etc along with setting the limit of 3g Data.

Answer (score 0):

@Andy - Please try Phone Usage Monitor .

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rachittechnology.PhoneUsageMonitor

App to monitor your Internet ( 4G/3G/Edge/GPRS/Wifi ), Phone calls ( Incoming/outgoing ) & Call History reports.
Key features of ' Phone Usage Monitor ' -
- Track your phone usage real time to avoid extra charges on your bill

- View your Wifi and Internet Usage
- Track historical data to understand your calling patterns
- Detail reports as per your billing cycle
- Intuitive reports available at single click
- Generate Customized Reports
- Share and print your report
- No Internet connection required
- Progress bar on top ( marked in green/ yellow/ red color ) displays current data/phone usage

**PS - I'm creator of this app**

Any feedback is highly appreciated